# javascript get value from table

Tags: javascript, html

I have table this :

```
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
result =<input type="text">
```

using javascript how to show id value on input when click selected href rows, thanks

Comment: can't you use `<a id="123" href="#">select</a>`?

Comment: The reason all the jQuery answers should be downvoted is because jQuery responses are all telling the user to use an entire library (which can cost resources to add) for something that can be solved using small amounts of pure JS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do it like this:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7cbJQ/2/).

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#table a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#result').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td><a href="#">select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
result = <input id="result" type="text">
```

Comment: @Event_Horizon not quite right, jQuery is a libary in javascript, but indeed it is not "raw" javascript

Comment: please see my solution it uses PURE JS

Comment: @ZombieSpy yes, its a library, if the user doesn't specifically say they are using jQuery already, you are telling them to add a LIBRARY OF CODE for one issue that can be resolved with small amounts of pure JS, that's retarded

Comment: I looked a lot of the questions on here and its generally considered very bad form on this site to give jquery answers on questions without the tag "jquery" on it, probably because when its not tagged jquery it means a level of manual control is desired in that someone does not want a whole library of code for a specific issue. Even if the OP was complete noob and wanted jquery, a question not tagged jquery should be taken as a chance to exercise advanced javascript development skills instead of just resorting to jquery all the time - at least, that seems to be the majority opinion on SO.

Comment: in this case it seems the OP was satisfied with jQuery and marked this as the answer, even if OP did not tag question jQuery - in the big picture, ultimately the OP's  end satisfaction is all that's important.

Comment: @Event_Horizon Actually, jQuery *is* JavaScript. However, JavaScript is not jQuery.

Comment: @sajawikio SO is not just about providing the OP with a "make it work" scenario. We should be promoting the *best* solution. Sometimes the OP is not aware of the existence of such plugins as jQuery. We are supposed to be helping, not competing (which seems to be what's going on with the downvotes).

Answer (score 3):

Give an id of 'result' to the input element and try this,

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var links = table.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
    links[x].onclick = function() {
      var parentCell = this.parentNode;
      var parentRow = parentCell.parentNode;

      var idCell = parentRow.cells[parentCell.cellIndex-1]
      var id = idCell.textContent;

      document.getElementById('result').value = id;

    }

}
```

Quick JS Fiddle here,
http://jsfiddle.net/X8vEx/

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

PURE JS!!

http://jsfiddle.net/vQBZJ/7/

Using HTML4 compatible code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++)
{
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event)
                            {
                              event.preventDefault();
                              var res= document.getElementById("result");

                              res.value = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
                            }
                            , false);
}
```

HTML5 only:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vQBZJ/2/

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++)
{
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event)
                            {
                              event.preventDefault();
                              var res= document.querySelector("#result");

                              res.value = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("td").innerHTML;
                            }
                            , false);
}
```

Comment: P.S. I assume your result button has the id of result so I changed your HTML in that way (see the JSFIDDLE)

Comment: i assume `result =[object NodeList]` is not what he wanted?

Comment: sorry it was the earlier version, not the one where i succeeded i updated my post with the correct answer thx for pointing it  out

Comment: it looks a lot better then other answers (except another one)

Comment: `.querySelector` comes with HTML5. It's worth mentioning that it may not be supported in many browser versions. Consider replacing this (and the entire solution) with jQuery. jQuery will work in ALL major browser versions.

Comment: you dont need queryselector - u make a good point - i updated my code again

Comment: I agree that jQuery is better - but OP did not tag as jquery which means JS only solution! I also agree that my original solution is only for HTML5 - now I took out query selector and queryselector all so it is backwards compatible and it still works

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SelectVal(ele)
{
    document.getElementById("result").value = ele.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;
}
</script>

<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="SelectVal(this);">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="SelectVal(this);">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="SelectVal(this);">select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Result = <input id="result" type="text">
```

Comment: @aiep Although this works, I would recommend one of the jQuery solutions. This code is much more difficult to maintain. Multiple onclick registrations, duplicate IDs, etc.

Comment: this is not so good u keep having to modify yoru HTML. @aiep please see my solution it is more decoupled from the HTML.

Comment: @flem I made it easier to use

Comment: .children behaves differently across browsers. If I'm remembering correctly, FF includes "text nodes" such as text and comments. So as much as it may work, it's not foolproof. Consider IDs or classes on the `td` to make sure  you get the correct element.

Answer (score -1):

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) for simplifying this

```
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="getId(this)">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="getId(this)">select</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="getId(this)">select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
function getId(e){
alert(e.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Comment: use jquery to simplify and easy to get the value

Answer (score -2):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table#table a').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $(this).parent().prev('td').text().trim();

        $('table#table').next('input').val(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: He has asked in Javascript..not Jquery

Comment: @BhushanFirake jQuery is a plugin for JS. SO is not just about giving the OP EXACTLY what they want but also suggesting improvements. jQuery is more or less standard these days.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Ah. I wonder why this one took two downvotes? They're all working answers. Insane.